# Bean property 'cmpcode' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting following error in my 'cmpmstaddedit.jsp':

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'cmpcode' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property
>   'cmpcode' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the
>   return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:716)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:149)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin.cmpmstmgmt_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(cmpmstmgmt_jsp.java:330)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin.cmpmstmgmt_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(cmpmstmgmt_jsp.java:269)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin.cmpmstmgmt_jsp._jspService(cmpmstmgmt_jsp.java:123)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

The file 'cmpmstaddedit.jsp' is as below:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : cmpmstaddedit
    Created on : Aug 3, 2014, 1:18:10 PM
--%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:url var="actionUrl" value="save" />

<form:form id="cmpmstForm" commandName="cmpmsts" method="post" action="${actionUrl}" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpcode">Code</label>
            <form:input path="cmpcode" placeholder="Company Code" maxlength="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpdescr">Price</label>
            <form:input path="cmpdescr" placeholder="Company Description" maxlength="30" />
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpfybegin">Price</label>
            <form:input path="cmpfybegin" placeholder="F.Y. Begin Date" maxlength="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpfyend">Price</label>
            <form:input path="cmpfyend" placeholder="F.Y. End Date" maxlength="15" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

My model file 'CmpMst.java' is as below:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.nej.cmpmst.model;

/**
 *
 */
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="cmpmst", catalog = "nioerpj")
public class CmpMst {

    @Id
    private Byte cmpcode;
    private String cmpdescr;
    private Date cmpfybegin;
    private Date cmpfyend;

    public Byte getCmpcode() {
        return cmpcode;
    }
    public void setCmpcode(Byte cmpcode) {
        this.cmpcode = cmpcode;
    }

    public String getCmpdescr() {
        return cmpdescr;
    }
    public void setCmpdescr(String cmpdescr) {
        this.cmpdescr = cmpdescr;
    }

    public Date getCmpfybegin() {
        return cmpfybegin;
    }
    public void setCmpfybegin(Date cmpfybegin) {
        this.cmpfybegin = cmpfybegin;
    }

    public Date getCmpfyend() {
        return cmpfyend;
    }
    public void setCmpfyend(Date cmpfyend) {
        this.cmpfyend = cmpfyend;
    }

}
```

I have searched the internet and found many similar cases, however, even after applying the given solution doesn't resolved my issue. Can somebody help solving an issue? Do I need to upload any other file to arrive at a conclusion?

EDIT:

My Controller File CmpMstController.java is as below:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.nej.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.nej.cmpmst.model.CmpMst;
import com.nej.cmpmst.service.CmpMstService;

/**
 *
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/admin/cmpmstmgmt"})
public class CmpMstController {

    @Autowired
    private CmpMstService cmpmstService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addCmpMstPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("CmpMst-add");
        modelAndView.addObject("cmpmstmgmt", new CmpMst());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingCmpMst(@ModelAttribute CmpMst cmpmst) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("cmpmstmgmt");
        cmpmstService.addCmpMst(cmpmst);
        String message = "CmpMst was successfully added.";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/list","/"})
    public ModelAndView listOfCmpMsts() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/admin/cmpmstmgmt");
        List<CmpMst> cmpmsts = cmpmstService.getCmpMsts();
        modelAndView.addObject("cmpmsts", cmpmsts);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{cmpcode}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editCmpMstPage(@PathVariable Byte cmpcode) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("cmpmstmgmt");
        CmpMst cmpmst = cmpmstService.getCmpMst(cmpcode);
        modelAndView.addObject("cmpmst",cmpmst);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{cmpcode}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editingCmpMst(@ModelAttribute CmpMst cmpmst, @PathVariable Byte cmpcode) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("cmpmstmgmt");
        cmpmstService.updateCmpMst(cmpmst);
        String message = "CmpMst was successfully edited.";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{cmpcode}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteCmpMst(@PathVariable Byte cmpcode) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("cmpmstmgmt");
        cmpmstService.deleteCmpMst(cmpcode);
        String message = "CmpMst was successfully deleted.";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

My cmpmstmgmt.jsp is as below:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : cmpmstmgmt
    Created on : Jul 26, 2014, 6:00:28 PM
    Author     : Tushar
--%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="../../../resources/mytheme/styles/pure-0.4.2.css"/>'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="../../../resources/mytheme/styles/jquery-ui.css"/>'>
    <style type="text/css">
    th {
        text-align: left
    }
    </style>

    <div class="body">

    <div style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="bookDialog" style="display: none;">
        <%@ include file="cmpmstaddedit.jsp"%>
    </div>
    <h1>List Of Company Master</h1>
    <button class="pure-button pure-button-primary" onclick="addCmpMst()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Company Master
    </button>
    <br>
        <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered pure-tablestriped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="4%">Sr.No.</th>
                    <th width="12%">Code</th>
                    <th width="12%">Company Description</th>
                    <th width="12%">F.Y. Begin Date</th>
                    <th width="12%">F.Y. End Date</th>
                    <th width="12%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${cmpmst}" var="user" varStatus="loopCounter">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${loopCounter.count}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${cmpmst.cmpcode}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${cmpmst.cmpdescr}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${cmpmst.cmpfybegin}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${cmpmst.cmpfyend}" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <nobr>
                                <button onclick="editCmpMst(${cmpmst.cmpcode});"
                                    class="pure-button pure-buttonprimary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
                                </button>
                                <a href="delete/${cmpmst.cmpcode}" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this CmpMst?');">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Delete
                                </a>
                                </nobr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<!-- It is advised to put the <script> tags at the end of the document body so that they don't block rendering of the page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="../../../resources/mytheme/script/jquery.js" />'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="../../../resources/mytheme/script/jquery-ui.js" />'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="../../../resources/mytheme/script/js-for-listuser.js"/>'></script>
    </div>

    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

I have uploaded controller file - CmpMstController.java and cmpmstmgmt.jsp file as above. Please suggest correction.

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/admin/cmpmstaddedit.jsp at line 16

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/admin/cmpmstaddedit.jsp at line 16

13:         <legend></legend>
14:         <div class="pure-control-group">
15:             <label for="cmpcode">Code</label>
16:             <form:input path="cmpcode" placeholder="Company Code" maxlength="15" />
17:         </div>
18:         <div class="pure-control-group">
19:             <label for="cmpdescr">Company Description</label>
```

EDIT: File - js-for-listcmpmst.js

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

function addCmpMst() {
$('#cmpmstDialog').dialog("option", "title", 'Add Company');
$('#cmpmstDialog').dialog('open');
}
function editCmpMst(cmpcode) {
$.get("get/" + cmpcode, function(result) {
$("#cmpmstDialog").html(result);
$('#cmpmstDialog').dialog("option", "title", 'Edit Company');
$("#cmpmstDialog").dialog('open');
initializeDatePicker();
});
}
function initializeDatePicker() {
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat : "dd/mm/yyyy",
changeMonth : true,
changeYear : true,
showButtonPanel : true
});
}
function resetDialog(form) {
form.find("input").val("");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cmpmstDialog').dialog({
autoOpen : false,
position : 'center',
modal : true,
resizable : false,
width : 440,
buttons : {
"Save" : function() {
    $('#cmpmstForm').submit();
    },
"Cancel" : function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
    }
},
close : function() {
    resetDialog($('#cmpmstForm'));
    $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});
initializeDatePicker();
});
```

Edited Controller file:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.nej.controller;

import com.nej.cmpmst.model.CmpMst;
import com.nej.cmpmst.service.CmpMstService;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author Tushar
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/admin/cmpmstmgmt"})
public class CmpMstController {

    @Autowired
    private CmpMstService cmpmstService;


    @RequestMapping(value={"/list","/"})
    public String listOfCmpMsts(Map<String, Object> map ) {
        map.put("cmpmst", new CmpMst());

        map.put("cmpmstList", cmpmstService.getCmpMsts());

        return "/admin/cmpmstmgmt";
    }

    @RequestMapping("get/{cmpcode}")
    public String getCmpMst(@PathVariable Byte cmpcode, Map<String, Object> map) {
        CmpMst cmpmst = cmpmstService.getCmpMst(cmpcode);

        map.put("cmpmst", cmpmst);

        return "admin/cmpmstaddedit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCmpMst(@ModelAttribute("cmpmst") CmpMst cmpmst, BindingResult result) {
        cmpmstService.saveCmpMst(cmpmst);

        return "redirect:list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{cmpcode}")
    public String deleteCmpMst(@PathVariable("cmpcode") Byte cmpcode) {
        cmpmstService.deleteCmpMst(cmpcode);

        return "redirect:/admin/cmpmstmgmt/";
    }


}
```

cmpmstaddedit.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : cmpmstaddedit
    Created on : Aug 3, 2014, 1:18:10 PM
    Author     : Tushar
--%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:url var="actionUrl" value="save" />

<form:form id="cmpmstaddedit" commandName="cmpmst" method="post" action="${actionUrl}" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpcode">Code</label>
            <form:input path="cmpcode" placeholder="Company Code" maxlength="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpdescr">Company Description</label>
            <form:input path="cmpdescr" placeholder="Company Description" maxlength="30" />
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpfybegin">F.Y. Begin Date</label>
            <form:input path="cmpfybegin" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="datepicker" />
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="cmpfyend">F.Y. End Date</label>
            <form:input path="cmpfyend" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="datepicker" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

Comment: From the stacktrace, I would say the error is in a file name `cmpmstmgmt.jsp` does it exists ? Also it looks that you try to access property `cmpcode` from a `List<CmpMst>` instead of a `CmpMst` ...

Comment: @falcon Please post your controller code.

Comment: @ankur, I have uploaded cmpmstmgmt.jsp and controller CmpMstController.java files, please suggest.

Comment: @Serge, cmpmstmgmt.jsp does exists and I have uploaded the same in my question above.

Comment: @falcon Please give some hints regarding the flow, which method is called first, what view it redirects , then which jsp page is called.

Comment: @ankur, When cmpmstmgmt.jsp is requested from the menu, controller CmpMstController.java is executed and wherein requestmapping for "/" is hit. This leads to a view cmpmstmgmt.jsp, and wherein list of companies will be displayed, with 'edit' and 'delete' button for each row and single 'add' button for the view. When 'add' or 'edit' button is clicked a javascript is executed and dialog file cmpmstaddedit.jsp is called, which displays single row either blank or with values depending on the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSP file you have :

```
<c:forEach items="${cmpmst}" var="user" varStatus="loopCounter">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${loopCounter.count}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${cmpmst.cmpcode}" /></td>
```

while `${cmpmst}` is an *array*. You should write instead :

```
<c:forEach items="${cmpmst}" var="user" varStatus="loopCounter">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${loopCounter.count}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.cmpcode}" /></td>
```

and same for following fields

I could not see how and where you forward to `cmpmstaddedit.jsp` in shown controller, but I assume that `cmpmsts` is also a list. You must ensure that you put a single object as request attribute before forwarding to that view.

Comment: @falcon the answer looks fine, please comment if it solves your problem.

Comment: @serge, I have implemented the suggested change, but result is the same. Error is on line 16 in the file 'cmpmstaddedit.jsp'. Above changes you have suggested is in the file 'cmpmstmgmt.jsp'. I have uploaded the exact exception text above, pl. see that.

Comment: @ankur, suggested solution has not solved the problem, I have narrated it in the above comment.

Comment: @serge, I have commented out the line         <%@ include file="cmpmstaddedit.jsp"%>    from the cmpmstmgmt.jsp file. Now application works. So, it seems that the issue is in file cmpmstaddedit.jsp.

Comment: @ankur, please see the above comment

Comment: @serge, I am using .js file which I have uploaded in my post from where, I am forwarding to cmpmstaddedit.jsp. Pl. see the post.

Comment: @falcon it confirms what I write in my edit : you pass a list to your jsp, and try to use it as a single element.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have to dig deeper to see, how do I need to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: @falcon I dn't know if that is the problem or type,

You have used `commandName="cmpmsts"` in `cmpmstaddedit.jsp`, but putting `modelAndView.addObject("cmpmst",cmpmst); inside `editCmpMstPage() , GET Request``

Comment: @ankur, Based on Serge's suggestion, I have found the solution. Error was in the cmpmstaddedit.jsp and my controller code. I have posted the corrected code above.